# "IoC is not initialized." error when using DesignTime support in Caliburn Micro for cascaded ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, design-time

I have put the Bootstrapper in a separate assembly than ViewModels and Views.
However the DesignTime support seems to work for simple *ViewModel->*View visualizations when there is no other Screen embedded that needs to resolve the corresponding view. But I can't get it running for child ViewModels. I get an Exception instead...

**Container with Child ViewModel:**

```
<UserControl ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:DesignSomeContainerViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
    cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True ... >
  <ContentControl cal:View.Model={Binding PropertyWithChildModel} />
  // where PropertyWithChildModel is another Screen
```

The Screen within the property is working correctly when displaying on it's own at DesignTime but not inside the ContentControl of another View... then the DesignTime support gets broken. I followed the guidance as suggested here [Caliburn Micro Documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/design-time). But there is nothing said about specialties when using nested resolving.

**My project structure:**

```
[Application.exe]
- MyNameSpace.ApplicationName
  - Bootstrapper (knows assemblies with views)
[Satellite.dll]
- MyNameSpace.SomeWhere
  - SomeContainerViewModel
    - [DesignTime]/DesignSomeContainerViewModel (Folder is Namespaceprovider)
  - SomeContainerView (SomeContainerView is set to look at DesignSomeContainerViewModel at DesignTime)
  - [MyChilds]/SomeChildViewModel
    - [DesignTime]/DesignSomeChildViewModel
  - [MyChilds]/SomeChildView (SomeChildView is set to look at DesignSomeChildViewModel)
```

**Class model:**

```
public interface ISomeChildViewModel
{
    string SomeValue {get;}
}

// should not be used during design time
public class SomeChildViewModel : Screen, ISomeChildViewModel
{
     // real implementation
}

// this is used at design time
public class DesignSomeChildViewModel : Screen, ISomeChildViewModel
{
   public DesignSomeChildViewModel()
   {
       this.SomeValue = "Hello World!";
       // showing up correctly in the Xaml View at DesignTime
   }

    string SomeValue {get;set;}
}

public interface ISomeContainerViewModel
{
    IScreen PropertyWithChildModel{get;}
}

// should not be used during design time
public class SomeContainerViewModel : Screen, ISomeContainerViewModel
{
    // real implementation
}

// used during design time
public class DesignSomeContainerViewModel : Screen, ISomeContainerViewModel
{
   public DesignSomeContainerViewModel ()
   {
       // this assignment leads to an exception that the IoC is not ready
       // "IoC is not initialized."
       this.PropertyWithChildModel = new DesignSomeChildViewModel();
   }

    IScreen PropertyWithChildModel
    {
       get { return propertyWithChildModel; }
       set
       {
            this.propertyWithChildModel=value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange();
       }
    }
}
```

**What I already tried/checked:**

- Bootstrapper: list of assemblies from SelectAssembly contains assembly with Views
- ViewModelLocator: was set to match against DesignTime ViewModel instead of ViewModel (even if not, there should be a message that the View can't be resolved for the ViewModel)
- used Conductor with ActiveItem instead of simple property
- the container DesignSomeContainerViewModel and SomeContainerViewModel share same interface with IScreen PropertyWithChild {get;} and binding points to the right property

Comment: ... also posted this as an issue in the tracking list of Caliburn.Micro here https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/358